# jQuery can't clone() and appendTo() with html before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, jquery-clone

People am here because am having this code that actually doesnt work, it bassically duplicate a row and make a new row for a new entry. Am ussing `clone()` and `appendTo()`.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xBioClown/363m6dsy/3/)**

But if you remove the last part of the html it will work, it seems like if there is a new tag it goes worng syntax, please could someone help me with this trouble?.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello world!</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues in your fiddle

1: the row element selected to be cloned is wrong.

2: parent element should be table but that is wrongly selected.

You can use the below modified code for cloning and appending the row.

```
 $("#clone").click(function() {
    i++;
    $("#remove").removeAttr("disabled");
    var parent = $("#data");
    var tr = $("#data tr:last");
    console.log(tr);
    var e = tr.clone().appendTo(parent);
    $(e).find("[type=text],[type=hidden]").each(function() {
      $(this).val('');
    });
  });
```

updated Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/363m6dsy/6/

Answer (score 0):

Change the selector and use `.after()` to append

```
var tr = $("#parent:last");

    var e = $("#parent").clone();
    $(tr).after(e);
```

**FULL JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $("#clone").click(function() {
    i++;
    $("#remove").removeAttr("disabled");
    var tr = $("#parent:last");

    var e = $("#parent").clone();
    $(tr).after(e);
    console.log(e);
    $(e).find("[type=text],[type=hidden]").each(function() {
      $(this).val('');
    });
  });
  $("#remove").click(function() {
    var tr = $("#parent:last-child");
    if (i > 1) {
      i--;
      tr.remove();
    }
    if (i == 1) {
      $("#remove").attr("disabled", "true");
    }
  });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/363m6dsy/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/363m6dsy/9/)**.

Just clone row `$("#parent").clone()` then append it `$('#data').append(e);` like :

```
$("#clone").click(function() {
    i++;
    $("#remove").removeAttr("disabled");

    var e = $("#parent").clone();

    $(e).find("[type=text],[type=hidden]").each(function() {
      $(this).val('');
    });

    $('#data').append(e);
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $("#clone").click(function() {
    i++;
    $("#remove").removeAttr("disabled");

    var e = $("#parent").clone();

    $(e).find("[type=text],[type=hidden]").each(function() {
      $(this).val('');
    });

    $('#data').append(e);
  });
  $("#remove").click(function() {
    var tr = $("#parent:last-child");
    if (i > 1) {
      i--;
      tr.remove();
    }
    if (i == 1) {
      $("#remove").attr("disabled", "true");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 700px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 130px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="data" name="data">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="9">
      <input type="button" value="Add" name="clone" id="clone">
      <input type="button" value="Remove" name="remove" id="remove">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td rowspan="2">N°</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Activity</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Field1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Resources</td>
    <td colspan="2">Dates</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Field2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Date 1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Status</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td>Start Date</td>
    <td>End Date</td>
  </tr>
  <tr name="parent" id="parent">
    <td align="center">
      <input id="val[]" name="val[]" type="text" value="1" required>
      <input id="val[]" name="val[]" type="hidden" value="13256">
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input id="val[]" name="val[]" type="text" value="2" required>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input id="val[]" name="val[]" type="text" value="3" required>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input id="val[]" name="val[]" type="text" value="4" required>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input id="val[]" name="val[]" type="text" value="5" required>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input id="val[]" name="val[]" type="text" value="6" required>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input id="val[]" name="val[]" type="text" value="7" required>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input id="val[]" name="val[]" type="text" value="8" required>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input id="val[]" name="val[]" type="text" value="9" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello world!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```